# Eclipse doesn't find my java 8 library (mac)

Tags: java, eclipse

I have installed java 8 SDK on my mac and terminal says `java -version` is 
`java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)`

bur when i create a project in eclipse with JSE 1.8 this is what happens: 
[image]

as you can see, no library is assigned:

[image]

when i try to add a new environment, this is what i get:
[image]
any help or suggestions?

Comment: I think, you forgot `Content/Home` in JRE home path, but I'm not sure if that's necessary.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg I still get the ` Target is not a JDK root. System library was not found.` message and the Finish button is still disabled.

Answer (score 6):

You need to select the home, eg `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: This was my problem, and I assume his too.

Answer (score 2):

The link to your Java 8 environment must be broken. Go to `Window`, `Preferences`, search "jre", select `Installed JREs`, and create a new environnment. Give the path to a JDK rather than a JRE. Then, right click on your project, `Properties`, `Build path`, `Edit` the current JRE and replace it with the new one.

You will also need to right click on your project, `Properties`, `Java compiler`, and set the compiler compliance to 1.8.

Comment: I get the message `Target is not a JDK root. System library was not found.`. I have included the message's print screen in my post :(

Comment: You must select the whole folder. For example, mine is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0`. Also, are you sure you installed JDK and not only JRE ?

Answer (score -1):

I have Eclipse Luna 4.4 on my Mac OSX 10.10 and I was having the same issue. I was able to resolve it by going to Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs and "Add" the path to JRE home in the JDK: (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre). That did it